# Rename scrapy project

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I couldn't find much information on this. I want to rename my Scrapy project, spiders made, JSONs created but want to change the name to something meaningful without messing anything up.

A solution through the terminal would also be appreciated.

Comment: You want to change all the filenames in a folder? And all references to those filenames within the codes?

Comment: @Mortz No, just the project name, that we make with ```scrapy startproject tutorial``` though the terminal. There aren't any references of it within the code so I don't believe that's required.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to simply change the folder name from `tutorial` to `somethingelse`?

Comment: I haven't, because I didn't want to mess anything up. Thought someone experienced could help out.

Comment: Can't fix what is not broken - try and make a copy of your top level directory and see if something breaks. And let us know the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now there is no command that changes the project name from the command line. I would just rename it in your file explorer, it shouldn't mess with your spiders.

Comment: Change it in the settings manually as well?
Also, changing spider names and their classes directly wouldn't mess anything up either?

Comment: Yes, change the project name in the settings. As per the spider names I would recommend not changing the class name and just editing under the `name = 'ABC'`.

Answer (score 0):

Change project directory name, search old project name in scrapy.cfg and settings.py files and replace with new project name.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you only need to change `default = new_project_title` under `[settings]` in scrapy.cfg file and `SPIDER_MODULES = ['new_project_title.spiders']` in the settings.py file to make the spider run with the new name of the project.

After longer inspection of documentation, I have to say that the quick change of the project name through the scrapy's command line is not that easy.